# Disable ATI HDMI sound device - Fedora with PulseAudio

Tags: fedora, audio, pulseaudio, hdmi

I want to disable the ATI HDMI sound device.

I have nothing connected to it and for some reason, although it isn't the default sound device, it sometimes kicks in and grabs my sound, leaving the real sound device silent.

How can I block the system from using it?

I'm using Fedora 20 with PulseAudio. I don't use any DE, I prefer answer that doesn't include GUI configuration tool.

Answer (score 1):

If it has a unique driver, you can [blacklist](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/avoid-linux-kernel-module-driver-autoloading.html) the module.

(Edit: [Better Fedora link](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/Installation_Guide/rescuemode_drivers-blacklisting.html))

Comment: It seems that the link you provided is out of date. I have no modprobe.conf file in etc (which is the described method for Fedora). I have tried already to add the module to blcklist file in modprobe.d but that doesn't work.

Comment: The second link helped me blocking the module. Turns out it didn't work for me because the file must end with .conf. However, both my cards use the same module, so I can't use this method to disable the ATI Sound device.

Comment: Sorry, man... that's why I had the "if" at the beginning...