# Disable/Remove Audio Source (PulseAudio)

Tags: fedora, pulseaudio

In Windows, as a comparison, one can disable audio sources, so that when wanting to switch between them, one receives a shortened list of available audio sources to choose from.  To my understanding the driver supporting a device is getting disabled by doing that.  Can one do this on Linux(*) as well or would it be tricky as many drivers are very broad and general?

Right now, apart from the desired sound sources, I get one from my display, two from my USB headset (S/PDIF and analog) and another two from my built-in sound card (likewise S/PDIF and analog).  My aim is to reduce them to the two I use (analog built-in and analog headset) as the remainder is either undesired or does not have anything connected to it to emit any sound in the first place.

Contrary to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/263263/179000) I did not configure any particular module myself.  I also do not want to hinder the system to discover new devices, should I change to a new headset or different internal sound card, which would make [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109707/179000) not too useful either as it may block future devices.

Is there a way to do it during runtime?  If it needs to be done every time the system starts, something I can add into a script and start up at login would be also fine.

(*) For my system this is currently Fedora 33 using Cinnamon Desktop.

Answer (score 3):

List (any from: modules, sinks, sources,  sink-inputs,  source-outputs,  clients,  samples, cards)

```bsh
pactl list cards
```

Find the item you want to disable by `Name:`

```
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1 off
```

Add this as your autostart command.

Comment: Thank you!  I needed to retract my edit with the cards unfortunately as it appears that there are just three cards (which from the physical point of view is correct), but in Cinnamon Sound Settings there are 5 entries and they are still shown after having disabled the entire card of the display.  I would have expected it t o go down to four.

Comment: How do I turn the card back on? It seems that pactl cannot find the card when it's off when I run `pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1 on`.